# Como percorrer os casos do data.frame usando `dplyr`?

Tags: r

Estou a tentar analisar os casos (linhas) de um `data.frame` com `dplyr`, mas sem sucesso. Criei duas funções para isso:

```
f1 <- function(x) {
  c(s = sum(x), 
    m = mean(x), 
    v = var(x))
}

f2 <- function(x) {
  apply(x, 1, f1)
}
```

Meu `data.frame` (`data_1`):

```
for (i in 1:6) {
  assign(paste('var', i, sep = '_'), 
         runif(30, 20, 100))
}

data_1 <- do.call(
  cbind.data.frame, 
  mget(ls(pattern = '*v'))
)
```

Uso das funções do *package* `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

data_1 %>%
  mutate_at(.vars = vars (starts_with('v')),
            .funs = funs(.= f2))

data_1 %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, .funs = funs(.= f2))
```

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
>     Evaluation error: dim(X) must have a positive length.

Como a análise é feita nas linhas, e tenho três funções (soma, média e variância), o retorno esperado é de três colunas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aqui vão duas maneiras de fazer o que pede, uma com R base e a outra com o pacote `dplyr`.

Primeiro vou refazer os dados, com `set.seed` para tornar os resultados reprodutíveis. E dum modo mais fácil e natural que com chamadas a `assign`.

```
set.seed(1234)    # Torna os resultados reprodutíveis

data_1 <- as.data.frame(replicate(6, runif(30, 20, 100)))
names(data_1) <- paste0("var", 1:6)
```

Viu? Muito mais fácil

Solução R base.

```
cbind(data_1, t(f2(data_1)))
```

Solução `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

data_1 %>%
  bind_cols(data_1 %>% f2() %>% t() %>% as.data.frame())
```

Esta instrução aplica `bind_cols` com primeiro argumento o que vem do *pipe* `%>%` e segundo argumento o resultado da aplicação de `f2()` aos dados. Mas depois disso, é necessário transpor a matriz de saída de `f2()` e transformá-la em data.frame.

Talvez seja mais simples ter a saída da função `f2` já no formato requerido por `bind_cols`.

```
f2b <- function(x) {
  apply(x, 1, f1) %>% t() %>% as.data.frame()
}

data_1 %>%
  bind_cols(data_1 %>% f2b())
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma opção usando o pacote `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

#transformar o data frame em data.table
data_2 = as.data.table(data_1)

# criar os indices para indicar que o cálculo será feito para cada linha
data_2[, i := .I]

# vetor com nome das colunas para calcular
colNam = paste0('var_', 1:6)

# calcular soma, media e var para cada ID i (ou seja, cada linha)
data_2[, ":=" (s = sum(.SD), m = rowMeans(.SD), v = apply(.SD, 1, var)), by = i, .SDcols = colNam]

# remover coluna ID
data_2[, i := NULL]
```

Answer (score 3):

### O erro

A mensagem de erro indica que a função `apply()`, chamada por `f2()` está sendo rodada em um objeto que não tem duas dimenções. Isso ocorre porque o mutate vai tentar aplicar a função em cada uma das colunas, que de fato não tem duas dimensões.

### A solução

Executar operações por linha é uma questão não trivial dentro do [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse). Isso ocorre porque este pacote/filosofia foi pensado para trabalhar com tabelas em formato longo e por grupos.

A maior prova disso é que já houveram esforços de três grandes desenvolvedores do `tidyverse` para atacar essa questão. O Hadley Wickham criou [purrrlyr](https://github.com/hadley/purrrlyr), a Jenny Bryan tratou o tema [aqui](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/row-oriented-workflows-in-r-with-the-tidyverse) (e principalmente [aqui](https://github.com/jennybc/row-oriented-workflows/blob/master/iterate-over-rows.md)) e o próprio Romain François, atual mantenedor do [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr), criou recentemente [este pacote](https://github.com/romainfrancois/rap).

A resposta que ofereço então, será usar o `purrr::transpose()` para resolver a questão.

O [purrr](/questions/tagged/purrr) oferece a função `transpose` que torna `lista[[1]]][[2]]` em `lista[[2]][[1]]`. Usando essa função podemos criar uma `coluna-lista` para cada linha.

```
tidy_data <- data_1 %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(linhas = transpose(data_1) %>% map(unlist))

tidy_data
# A tibble: 30 x 7
    var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6 linhas   
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <list>   
 1  29.1  56.5  89.2  33.3  79.5  55.1 <dbl [6]>
 2  69.8  41.2  23.3  92.0  93.3  38.3 <dbl [6]>
 3  68.7  44.4  45.4  30.7  99.6  26.6 <dbl [6]>
 4  69.9  60.6  21.1  30.5  95.4  88.0 <dbl [6]>
 5  88.9  34.5  39.1  28.4  58.9  38.8 <dbl [6]>
 6  71.2  80.8  76.5  60.9  42.7  99.1 <dbl [6]>
 7  20.8  36.1  44.6  44.0  40.1  68.2 <dbl [6]>
 8  38.6  40.7  60.7  22.1  60.3  99.9 <dbl [6]>
 9  73.3  99.4  24.1  44.8  59.8  50.0 <dbl [6]>
10  61.1  84.6  65.2  79.4  45.5  64.4 <dbl [6]>
# ... with 20 more rows
```

Depois de isso feito, basta aplicar sua função para cada linha com `mutate()` + `map()`.

```
tidy_data %>% 
  mutate(estats = map(linhas, f1))

# A tibble: 30 x 8
    var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6 linhas    estats   
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <list>    <list>   
 1  29.1  56.5  89.2  33.3  79.5  55.1 <dbl [6]> <dbl [3]>
 2  69.8  41.2  23.3  92.0  93.3  38.3 <dbl [6]> <dbl [3]>
 3  68.7  44.4  45.4  30.7  99.6  26.6 <dbl [6]> <dbl [3]>
 4  69.9  60.6  21.1  30.5  95.4  88.0 <dbl [6]> <dbl [3]>
 5  88.9  34.5  39.1  28.4  58.9  38.8 <dbl [6]> <dbl [3]>
 6  71.2  80.8  76.5  60.9  42.7  99.1 <dbl [6]> <dbl [3]>
 7  20.8  36.1  44.6  44.0  40.1  68.2 <dbl [6]> <dbl [3]>
 8  38.6  40.7  60.7  22.1  60.3  99.9 <dbl [6]> <dbl [3]>
 9  73.3  99.4  24.1  44.8  59.8  50.0 <dbl [6]> <dbl [3]>
10  61.1  84.6  65.2  79.4  45.5  64.4 <dbl [6]> <dbl [3]>
# ... with 20 more rows
```

A solução acima deixa o resultado numa coluna-lista, caso fique desconfortável com elas podemos expandir o `mutate` e teremos

```
tidy_data %>% 
  mutate(s = map_dbl(linhas, sum),
         m = map_dbl(linhas, mean),
         v = map_dbl(linhas, sd))

# A tibble: 30 x 10
    var1  var2  var3  var4  var5  var6 linhas        s     m     v
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <list>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  29.1  56.5  89.2  33.3  79.5  55.1 <dbl [6]>  343.  57.1  24.0
 2  69.8  41.2  23.3  92.0  93.3  38.3 <dbl [6]>  358.  59.7  29.7
 3  68.7  44.4  45.4  30.7  99.6  26.6 <dbl [6]>  315.  52.6  27.4
 4  69.9  60.6  21.1  30.5  95.4  88.0 <dbl [6]>  365.  60.9  30.0
 5  88.9  34.5  39.1  28.4  58.9  38.8 <dbl [6]>  289.  48.1  22.4
 6  71.2  80.8  76.5  60.9  42.7  99.1 <dbl [6]>  431.  71.9  19.0
 7  20.8  36.1  44.6  44.0  40.1  68.2 <dbl [6]>  254.  42.3  15.4
 8  38.6  40.7  60.7  22.1  60.3  99.9 <dbl [6]>  322.  53.7  26.9
 9  73.3  99.4  24.1  44.8  59.8  50.0 <dbl [6]>  351.  58.6  25.8
10  61.1  84.6  65.2  79.4  45.5  64.4 <dbl [6]>  400.  66.7  13.9
# ... with 20 more rows
```

Outra solução possível seria jogar a tabela num formato longo, agrupar os dados por linhas e criar um sumário com as estatísticas.

Estas soluções são mais robustas do que transformar a tabela em matriz porque na matriz pode ocorrer a coerção dos dados para `character` caso haja uma coluna deste tipo na tabela.