# Como calcular a mediana de uma linha em um data.frame no R?

Tags: r, matemática, data.frame

Tenho um banco de dados e o meu objetivo é realizar algumas análises de comportamento de classes por linha.

Exemplo:

```
print(DADOS)

 Linha  A   B   C   D   E
 L1     4   3   2   2   4
 L2     1   11  1   1   1
 L3     0   1   2   3   4
 L4     2   0   0   8   0
```

Usando o exemplo acima, para analisar as classes A, B, C, D e E, a princípio eu usei a Soma e a Média de cada linha.
Sendo a melhor forma ou não, para calcular a Soma e a Média eu usei a função `mutate` da seguinte maneira:

```
DADOS = DADOS %>%
select(Linha:E) %>%
mutate(Soma = (A+B+C+D+E)) %>%
mutate(Média = Soma/5)
```

E a minha base de dados ficou assim:

```
print(DADOS)

    Linha  A   B   C   D   E   Soma  Média
    L1     4   3   2   2   4   15    3
    L2     1   11  1   1   1   15    3
    L3     0   1   2   3   4   10    2
    L4     2   0   0   8   0   10    2
```

No exemplo acima podemos verificar que apesar das linhas possuírem dados diferentes, as linhas `L1` e `L2` possuem a `Soma` e a `Média` idênticas, o mesmo acontece com a `Soma` e a `Média` das linhas `L3` e `L4`.

Como a `Soma` e a `Média` não foram tão efetivas, podemos incluir mais um outro cálculo para a análise: a Mediana.

**Como funciona a Mediana?**

Na prática, a Mediana ordena um conjunto de dados e identifica o seu elemento central.

Exemplo:

L4 = {2, 0, 0, 8, 0}

Ordenando L4 = {0,0,**0**,2,8}

Mediana L4 = 0

A Mediana divide um conjunto de dados em partes iguais, afim de encontrar uma tendência de distribuição mais assertiva. O uso da Mediana é ideal para identificar valores em seu conjunto de dados que fogem do padrão, os famosos "fora de série".

Sabendo disso, a questão é: Como posso calcular a Mediana de uma linha em um data.frame?

Comment: Veja a função `median()`. `?median`

Comment: Eu conheço a função `median`, mas não sei como usar a função para calcular os valores na linha.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uma solução pode ser a seguinte.

```
library(dplyr)

DADOS %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Soma = (A + B + C + D + E),
         Média = Soma/5,
         Mediana = median(c(A, B, C, D, E)))
#Source: local data frame [4 x 9]
#Groups: <by row>
#
## A tibble: 4 x 9
#  Linha     A     B     C     D     E  Soma Média Mediana
#  <fct> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>   <int>
#1 L1        4     3     2     2     4    15     3       3
#2 L2        1    11     1     1     1    15     3       1
#3 L3        0     1     2     3     4    10     2       2
#4 L4        2     0     0     8     0    10     2       0
```

**Dados.**

```
DADOS <- read.table(text = "
Linha  A   B   C   D   E
 L1     4   3   2   2   4
 L2     1   11  1   1   1
 L3     0   1   2   3   4
 L4     2   0   0   8   0                    
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Rui Barradas, vou testar.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Ótima solução!

Answer (score 6):

Um pouco da explicação está [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/363177/43953).

Reproduzindo os dados

```
library(tidyverse)
txt <- "Linha  A   B   C   D   E
 L1     4   3   2   2   4
 L2     1   11  1   1   1
 L3     0   1   2   3   4
 L4     2   0   0   8   0"

DADOS <- as_tibble(
  read.table(text = txt, header = TRUE)
)
```

E então basta usar o `transpose()` para aplicar a `median()` para cada linha.

```
DADOS %>% 
  mutate(
    linhas = DADOS %>% select(-1) %>% 
      transpose() %>% map(unlist),
    mediana = map_dbl(linhas, median)
  ) %>% 
select(-linhas) 

# A tibble: 4 x 7
  Linha     A     B     C     D     E mediana
  <fct> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>   <dbl>
1 L1        4     3     2     2     4       3
2 L2        1    11     1     1     1       1
3 L3        0     1     2     3     4       2
4 L4        2     0     0     8     0       0
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Tomás Barcellos, vou testar.

Answer (score 5):

Uma alternativa que surgiu recentemente é usar o pacote [`rap`](https://github.com/romainfrancois/rap):

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 3.5.2
library(rap)

txt <- "Linha  A   B   C   D   E
 L1     4   3   2   2   4
 L2     1   11  1   1   1
 L3     0   1   2   3   4
 L4     2   0   0   8   0"

DADOS <- as_tibble(
  read.table(text = txt, header = TRUE)
)

DADOS %>% 
  rap(
    soma = numeric() ~ A + B + C + D + E,
    media = numeric() ~ mean(c(A, B, C, D, E)),
    mediana =  numeric() ~ median(c(A, B, C, D, E))
    )
#> # A tibble: 4 x 9
#>   Linha     A     B     C     D     E  soma media mediana
#>   <fct> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 L1        4     3     2     2     4    15     3       3
#> 2 L2        1    11     1     1     1    15     3       1
#> 3 L3        0     1     2     3     4    10     2       2
#> 4 L4        2     0     0     8     0    10     2       0
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

A vantagem do `rap` em relação ao `rowise` é que ele permite especificar o tipo do output, o que pode te ajudar a evitar alguns erros.

Existe um repositório com bastante informação legal sobre [*Row Oriented Workflows* aqui](https://github.com/jennybc/row-oriented-workflows).

No seu caso eu não descartaria o `gather + group_by` também, apesar de isso não colocar as colunas exatamente na ordem que vc precisa.

```
DADOS %>% 
  gather(k, v, A:E) %>% 
  group_by(Linha) %>% 
  summarise(
    soma = sum(v),
    media = mean(v),
    mediana = mean(v)
  ) %>% 
  right_join(DADOS, by = "Linha")
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Daniel Falbel, vou testar.

Answer (score 3):

Aplicar funções em linhas é algo chatíssimo de fazer com `dplyr`. Eu prefiro transpor o data frame, resolver o problema nas colunas e depois organizar o resultado em um novo objeto:

```
resultado <- DADOS %>% 
  select(-LINHA) %>% # tirando LINHA pra poder aplicar as funcoes que interessam
  t() %>% # data frame transposto
  as.data.frame() %>% # precisa converter em data frame pra funcionar
  summarise_all(c(sum, mean, median)) %>% # aplicando as tres funcoes simultaneamente
  matrix(., ncol=3) # oraganizando o resultado como ele deve ficar

DADOS <- cbind(DADOS, resultado)

names(DADOS) <- c(names(DADOS)[1:6], "Soma", "Média", "Mediana")
DADOS
##   LINHA A  B C D E Soma Média Mediana
## 1    L1 4  3 2 2 4   15     3       3
## 2    L2 1 11 1 1 1   15     3       1
## 3    L3 0  1 2 3 4   10     2       2
## 4    L4 2  0 0 8 0   10     2       0
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Marcus Nunes, vou testar.

Answer (score 3):

O método mais rápido é usando `data.table` juntamente com o pacote `matrixStats` (pacote `rap` ainda está em desenvolvimento portanto não vou usá-lo mas suspeito que seja bem eficiente).

Para efeitos comparativos, eu vou adicionar 200k linhas a `DADOS`:

```
# carregar pacote
library(data.table)

DADOS <- read.table(text = "
Linha  A   B   C   D   E
 L1     4   3   2   2   4
 L2     1   11  1   1   1
 L3     0   1   2   3   4
 L4     2   0   0   8   0                    
", header = TRUE)

# adicionar linhas
set.seed(1)
m <- data.table(Linha = NA, 
                matrix(data= round(runif(n=1e6,1,15)), 
            ncol = 5))

data.table::setnames(m, paste0("V", 1:5), LETTERS[1:5])


# novo DADOS, com 200k+4 linhas
DADOS <- data.table::rbindlist(list(DADOS, m))

# nomeie colunas para estatisticas descritivas para facilitar remoção
cols <- c("Soma", "Media", "Mediana")
```

O primeiro método é o mais rápido, usando `data.table` com o `matrixStats`:

```
system.time(
  DADOS[, `:=`(Soma = matrixStats::rowSums2(as.matrix(.SD), na.rm=T),
            Media = matrixStats::rowMeans2(as.matrix(.SD), na.rm=T),
            Mediana = matrixStats::rowMedians(as.matrix(.SD), na.rm=T)),
        .SDcols=LETTERS[1:5]]
)
```

Resultado:

```
  user  system elapsed 
   0.08    0.03    0.11 
> head(DADOS)
   Linha A  B C  D E Soma Media Mediana
1:    L1 4  3 2  2 4   15   3.0       3
2:    L2 1 11 1  1 1   15   3.0       1
3:    L3 0  1 2  3 4   10   2.0       2
4:    L4 2  0 0  8 0   10   2.0       0
5:  <NA> 5 12 7 11 5   40   8.0       7
6:  <NA> 6  8 3  8 7   32   6.4       7
```

O segundo método é usando apeans `data.table` e adicionado `by=1:nrow(DADOS)`:

```
DADOS[, (cols) := NULL] # delete as colunas descritivas
# solucao apenas com data.table - ineficiente
system.time(
  DADOS[, `:=`(Soma = sum(.SD, na.rm=T),
               Media = mean(as.numeric(.SD), na.rm=T),
               Mediana = median(as.numeric(.SD), na.rm=T)), 
        .SDcols=LETTERS[1:5], by=1:nrow(DADOS)]
)
```

Resultado:

```
   user  system elapsed 
  65.71    0.26   67.78 
> head(DADOS)
   Linha A  B C  D E Soma Media Mediana
1:    L1 4  3 2  2 4   15   3.0       3
2:    L2 1 11 1  1 1   15   3.0       1
3:    L3 0  1 2  3 4   10   2.0       2
4:    L4 2  0 0  8 0   10   2.0       0
5:  <NA> 5 12 7 11 5   40   8.0       7
6:  <NA> 6  8 3  8 7   32   6.4       7
```

Usando `dplyr`:

```
DADOS[, (cols) := NULL] # delete as colunas descritivas
library(dplyr)
system.time(
 DADOS <-  DADOS %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(Soma = (A + B + C + D + E),
           Média = Soma/5,
           Mediana = median(c(A, B, C, D, E))) %>% 
   ungroup()
)
```

Resultado:

```
   user  system elapsed 
  69.95    0.17   72.57 
> head(DADOS)
# A tibble: 6 x 9
  Linha     A     B     C     D     E  Soma Média Mediana
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 L1        4     3     2     2     4    15   3         3
2 L2        1    11     1     1     1    15   3         1
3 L3        0     1     2     3     4    10   2         2
4 L4        2     0     0     8     0    10   2         0
5 NA        5    12     7    11     5    40   8         7
6 NA        6     8     3     8     7    32   6.4       7
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @JdeMello, vou testar.

Answer (score 1):

Para aplicar funções em linhas/colunas, você pode utilizar a função `apply` da base do R.

No seu exemplo, para criar uma coluna nova com a mediana das linhas, e para acrescentar ao seu data frame a função `cbind`:

`cbind(DADOS, mediana=apply(DADOS[,-1], 1, median))`

Explicando o comando:

O primeiro argumento do cbind: `DADOS` é o seu dataframe original que irá receber a nova coluna.
O segundo argumento do cbind `mediana=apply(DADOS[,-1], 1, median)` é a nova coluna que recebe o nome de mediana.

No apply o primeiro argumento é o dataframe. Repare que excluí a primeira coluna, uma vez que essa não é uma variável numérica e não deve entrar para o cálculo da mediana (ou qualquer outra estatística que desejar);
O segundo arumento é o `1` que significa para aplicar a função do terceiro argumento nas linhas. Se fosse utilizado o valor `2`, a função seria aplicada às colunas.
O terceiro argumento é a função que deseja aplicar. Você pode utilizar funções prontas ou customizadas, por exemplo se quisesse calcular a média mais 2, usaria `apply(mediana2=apply(DADOS[,-1], 1, function(x) median(x)+2`

```
      Linha  A  B  C  D  E  mediana
1     L1     4  3  2  2  4       3
2     L2     1 11  1  1  1       1
3     L3     0  1  2  3  4       2
4     L4     2  0  0  8  0       0
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Lucas Ferreira, vou testar.

Answer (score 1):

Com uso de funções do *package* `purrr` você pode fazer análise *byrow* de forma mais simples. Além disso, sabendo que a mediana só pode ser calculada em números, podes analisar os vetores pelas suas classes. Pegando o exemplo do @Rui Barradas:

```
dados <- read.table(text = "
Linha  A   B   C   D   E
 L1     4   3   2   2   4
 L2     1   11  1   1   1
 L3     0   1   2   3   4
 L4     2   0   0   8   0                    
", header = TRUE)
```

A análise fica assim:

```
library(tidyverse)

dados %>% 
  mutate(var = pmap(.l = Filter(is.numeric, .), 
                    .f = lift_vd(..f = median)))

  Linha A  B C D E var
1    L1 4  3 2 2 4   3
2    L2 1 11 1 1 1   1
3    L3 0  1 2 3 4   2
4    L4 2  0 0 8 0   0
```

Mais fácil.